# IEnumerable items disappearing before being used using LINQ Where

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I'm fairly new to programming and I've been playing around with writing some random functions.

I wrote the below function which works loosely based on eratosthenes sieve. Initially though, I was having a problem with the updatedEntries IEnumerable.

The updatedEntites was sort of populating (something to do with deferred execution I gather - in debug mode the 'current' was null but the results view contained the relevant items) but when the RemoveWhere was applied to oddPrimesAndMultiples the items in updatedEntries disappeared even though I don't see why they should still be linked to the items in oddPrimesAndMultiples. (I could just be completely misunderstanding what's going on of course and the problem might be something else entirely!)

The problem doesn't arise if I change updatedEntries to a List rather than an IEnumerable and I've actually now rewritten that statement without using LINQ to (potentially?) make better use of the fact I'm using a SortedSet anyway...but I would still like to know why the issue arose in the first place!

Here is my code:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> QuickPrimes()
        {
            int firstPrime = 2;
            int firstOddPrime = 3;

            int currentValue = firstOddPrime;
            int currentMinimumMultiple;

            SortedSet<Tuple<int, int>> oddPrimesAndMultiples = new SortedSet<Tuple<int, int>>() { new Tuple<int, int> (firstOddPrime, firstOddPrime) };
            IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> updatedEntries;

            yield return firstPrime;
            yield return firstOddPrime;

            while (true)
            {
                currentMinimumMultiple = oddPrimesAndMultiples.First().Item1;
                while (currentValue < currentMinimumMultiple)
                {
                    yield return currentValue;
                    oddPrimesAndMultiples.Add(new Tuple<int, int> (currentValue * 3, currentValue));
                    currentValue += 2;
                }

                updatedEntries = oddPrimesAndMultiples.Where(tuple => tuple.Item1 == currentMinimumMultiple)
                                                        .Select(t => new Tuple<int, int>(t.Item1 + 2 * t.Item2, t.Item2));

                oddPrimesAndMultiples.RemoveWhere(t => t.Item1 == currentMinimumMultiple);
                oddPrimesAndMultiples.UnionWith(updatedEntries);
                currentValue += 2;
            }
        }
```

and the main where I'm testing the function:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            foreach(int prime in Problems.QuickPrimes())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(prime);
                if (prime > 20) return;
            } 
        }
```

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: An IEnumerable, using the yield keyword can provide very different results indeed. Use it wisely.

Comment: Let me see if I understand this, your code now as presented is working but previously it was not because you didn't have the ".ToList()" call on the updatedEntries assignation, correct?

Comment: Could you please provide [MCVE] of the problem? With current post it is not even clear if code have the issue you are talking about or not.

Comment: @Fredy Treboux and Alexei - apologies yet the .ToList() on the updatedEntries shouldn't be there - I forgot to remove it when pasting the code from my corrected code (I just changed the type of updatedEntries back from List to IEnumerable!) Without the ToList() call an InvalidOperation error occurs because the items are removed from updatedEntries as I wrote above and then this means oddPrimesAndMultiples is also entry leading to the error when I try to call first on it! Updated question as required.

Comment: Please explain a basic example of what you observe is happening, I find your question difficult to get a solid grasp on.

Answer (score 1):

The trap is that `updatedEntries` is defined in one line, but actually *executed* later.

To bring it back to the basics, see this code snippet (from Linqpad):

```
var ints = new SortedSet<int>( new[] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10});

var updatedEntries = ints.Where(i => i > 5); // No ToList()!
updatedEntries.Dump();
```

This shows `6, 7, 8, 9, 10`.

```
ints.RemoveWhere(i => i > 7);
updatedEntries.Dump();
```

Now this shows `6, 7`, because `updatedEntries` is re-executed.

```
ints.UnionWith(updatedEntries);
```

This adds `6, 7`, while you expected it to add the first listing `6, 7, 8, 9, 10`.

So when defining an `IEnumerable` you should always be aware of when it's actually executed. It always acts on the state of the program at that particular point.